# ProForms Basic error message after upgrade to Joomla 3

Tags: joomla-3.x, migration

I used the plugin MigrateMe to migrate my data from Joomla 1.5 to 3 and everything seems to work fine except for this specific plugin, ProForms Basic, which is the follow up to Mad4Joomla... When I try to create a new form of modify an existing one, it displays an error message with this:

```
Unknown column 'usermail' in 'field list' SQL=SELECT `usermail` FROM d6xcm_m4j_formelements WHERE `fid` ='4' AND `usermail` = '1' AND `active` = '1' LIMIT 1
```

Does anyone have an idea about it?

Comment: Migrating Joomla does not migrate 3rd party extensions. You need to install the Joomla 3.x compatible version of ProForms to get it working properly

Comment: You should read and follow the instructions of the Proforms developers about the proper way to upgrade the component.

Answer (score 1):

Try re-migrating the data for the extension from the old site. Not everything will work, but the current version will create all the necessary tables/columns and may eliminate this error.